# Get Google Cloud Project Number using its Id

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

I have Google Cloud Service account and projectId and want to get projectNumber programmatically from Java.

[image]

How can I get it?

Basically I have Service Account and want to use it for granting role "roles/storage.legacyBucketWriter" for the account "project-XXXXXXX@storage-transfer-service.iam.gserviceaccount.com" in the Google Cloud Storage Bucket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think GCP did not provide an API to map a project ID to a project number. But they did provide a [project list API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#listing_projects), after you get the list of the projects. You can map the project number by yourself.

Comment: Yes, I already saw this page but could not find how to do that in java API.

Comment: @DmitryGorkovets Can you be more specific on why you could not find how to do that in java API? Don't know how to use Java API calls?

Comment: Thanks! I took Java sample from https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list. Note that it is accessible in "v1" version. "v2" version does not have such functionality in CloudResourceManager.

Answer (score 39):

Not sure why they don't expose it directly, but you can do this (assuming your current configuration project corresponds to the desired project number):

```
gcloud projects list \
--filter="$(gcloud config get-value project)" \
--format="value(PROJECT_NUMBER)"
```

Comment: I had to do that programmatically from Java. Anyway I solved this issue, see my comment above.

Comment: I know the OP wanted a Java API for this, but... in case other searchers come here looking for the way to map a project_id to a project number using gcloud, this is not the best way to do it (not in October 2020 anyway).  Try this: `gcloud projects describe $PROJECT_ID --format="value(projectNumber)"` See the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/describe

Answer (score 9):

This gcloud command will return the project number:

```
gcloud projects describe $PROJECT_ID --format="value(projectNumber)"
```

You can then use this in a command to grant access such as:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID  --member=serviceAccount:$(gcloud projects describe $PROJECT_ID --format="value(projectNumber)")@@storage-transfer-service.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/storage.legacyBucketWriter
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an API now.

The jar version of the cloudresourcemanager java library supports it directly, as in the example here https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/get

With maven dependencies, you can do

pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-cloudresourcemanager -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-cloudresourcemanager</artifactId>
    <version>v2-rev20200617-1.30.9</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

CloudResourceManagerExample.java (adapted from the example by Google)

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.cloudresourcemanager.CloudResourceManager;
import com.google.api.services.cloudresourcemanager.model.Project;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class CloudResourceManagerExample {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    // The Project ID (for example, `my-project-123`).
    // Required.
    String projectId = "my-project-id"; // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    CloudResourceManager cloudResourceManagerService = createCloudResourceManagerService();

    String response = IOUtils.toString(cloudResourceManagerService.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl("https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + projectId)).execute().getContent(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    // TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
    System.out.println(response);
  }

  public static CloudResourceManager createCloudResourceManagerService()
      throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();
    if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
      credential =
          credential.createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
    }

    return new CloudResourceManager.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName("Google-CloudResourceManagerSample/0.1")
        .build();
  }
}
```

`response` will be something like `{"projectNumber": "123456", ...}`

In python you can do

```
# python3 -m pip install google.auth google-api-python-client
# from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/main/iam/api-client/quickstart.py
import google.auth
import googleapiclient.discovery
def initialize_service():
    """Initializes a Cloud Resource Manager service."""

    credentials, _ = google.auth.default(
        scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
    )
    crm_service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        "cloudresourcemanager", "v1", credentials=credentials
    )
    return crm_service

crm_service = initialize_service()
project = r.get(projectId=MY_PROJECT_ID).execute()
```

Comment: can we get project name instead of number and instead of java, can we do it with python

Comment: @user3713336 yeah I've added a python example at the end of my answer. The name will be `project['name']`

Comment: It gives the entire name- what if i just want the display name. Just want to print the display name

Comment: what? That's all the info. project['name'] is the display name isn't it name. what else do you want?

Comment: anyone is able to help me with this one - https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/16829/how-can-i-force-an-immediate-run-of-a-job-trigger

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is for Java, for those who might find it useful, here is a program to obtain a Google Project number from its ID in Go as well:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "google.golang.org/api/cloudresourcemanager/v1"
)

var projectID string

func main() {
    flag.StringVar(&projectID, "projectID", "", "Google Cloud Project ID")
    flag.Parse()

    cloudresourcemanagerService, err := cloudresourcemanager.NewService(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("NewService: %v", err)
    }

    project, err := cloudresourcemanagerService.Projects.Get(projectID).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Get project: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Project number for project %s: %d\n", projectID, project.ProjectNumber)
}
```

You can run it like so:

```
> go run main.go --projectID="my-project"
Project number for project my-project: 123456789817
```

(Note that this example uses Google Application Default Credentials (cf. https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/cloudresourcemanager/v1#hdr-Creating_a_client)).

Comment: can we get project name instead of number and instead of java, can we do it with python

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `gcloud projects describe <<project_id>>` ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/describe))

```
$ gcloud projects describe XXX
createTime: ...
lifecycleState: ...
name: ...
parent:
  id: ...
  type: ...
projectId: XXX
projectNumber: 'YYY'
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer doesn't do anything in Java but should work in many environments, i.e. `bash` or `zsh`, using tools most have access to during development or within containerized environments.

Assuming you're using some type of build process, you could trivially:

1. throw the following command into a docker container,
2. output the result (the project number) in a build step, and
3. store that in an environment variable for use in additional steps.

#### Using `gcloud`, `grep` , and `awk`

> *This assumes you have the string project name set in the `PROJECT_NAME` environment variable.*

This is a super simple solution using the Google Cloud SDK and the commonly available CLI tools `grep` and `awk`:

```sh
gcloud projects list | grep '${PROJECT_NAME} ' | awk '{print $3}'
```

> *Note: I suspect very big accounts with many projects may not want to query the entire list each time an individual project number is required. For those cases [@erkolson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54657449) is likely the best solution.*

Answer (score 0):

there are a list of api's that can provide it, from the command line would be:

```
gcloud projects list --filter="$(gcloud config get-value project)" --format="value(PROJECT_NUMBER)"
```

it is possible to get also the project id :

```
gcloud projects list --filter="$(gcloud config get-value project)" --format="value(PROJECT_ID)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you install the following package:

```
pip install google-cloud-resource-manager
```

Source code:

```
from google.cloud import resourcemanager_v3

def get_project_number(project_id):
    client = resourcemanager_v3.ProjectsClient()
    project = client.get_project(name=f"projects/{project_id}").name
    return project.split('/')[-1]

project_id = 'myprojectid'
project_number = get_project_number(project_id)
print(f"The project number for project {project_id} is: {project_number}")
```